# Unable to find action 'deleteItem' on the controller of c:RosterLineItemCmp

Tags: html, developer-console, button, developer, commandbutton

I am am really new to the development console on SF but I saw a pre-set  resources and was messing around with it to make a few action button. All worked except for the one that I edited to remove a student from the list. I keep getting the error

> Unable to find action 'deleteItem' on the controller of c:RosterLineItemCmp

Apologies for my commas and ; being all over the place Ive been trying all the was possible to make it work but no luck! Any help would be appreciated.

This is how it looks

## Component

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
    <!--TODO: Load jquery into parent component to save redundancy-->
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery311slim}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>
    
    <!-- Events -->
   <!-- <aura:registerEvent name="newCaseNote" type="c:NewTaskEvt"/>-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="editEventAttendance" type="c:EditEventAttendanceEvt"/>
   

    <aura:attribute name="rosterList" type="Event_Attendance__c[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="eventAttn" type="Event_Attendance__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="conId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="output" type="String"/>
    
    <!--
    <aura:attribute name="key" type="String"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="roster" type="Map"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="eventAttn" type="Object"/>
    -->

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    {!v.output}
    
    <div class="slds-button-group" role="group" style="float: right" >
 
        <button onclick="{!c.handleClick}" data-conId="{!v.conId}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected Contact-Attempt" >
          <lightning:icon  iconName="utility:missed_call" size="small" title="Contact Attempt"/> 
            <span class="slds-text-not-selected"/>
          <span class="slds-text-selected"/>
         <span class="slds-text-selected-focus"/>
              </button>
 <button onclick="{!c.editEventAttendance}" data-conId="{!v.conId}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:edit" size="small" title="Event Notes"/>
      </button>
        
           <button onclick="{!c.deleteItem}" data-conId="{!v.conId}" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-not-selected">
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="small" title="Remove Student"/>
      </button> 
        
     
    </div>
```

## Controller

```js
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    },

    doInit : function(cmp, helper) {
        var rosterList = cmp.get('v.rosterList');
        var eventAttn = cmp.get('v.eventAttn');
        console.log('test attn AHAHHA');
        console.dir(eventAttn);
        var displayName = eventAttn.Student__r.Name + ' - ' + eventAttn.Student__r.Summer_Team__c;
        //Display Contact Name.  Will throw exception if Contact not associated.  Handle with Try.
        try{cmp.set('v.output', displayName);}    
        catch(e){}   
    },

    scriptsLoaded : function(cmp, event, helper){
        helper.initializeButtonSelection(cmp, event);
    },
    
    editEventAttendance : function(cmp, evt, helper){
        helper.stageEventAttendance(cmp,evt,helper);
    },

    handleClick : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        helper.updateButtonSelection(cmp,evt);

    },

    createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Task"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();

},
    });

   // newTask : function (component, event, helper){
     //   Stage New Task event
    //  var newCaseNote = $A.get("e.c:NewTaskEvt");
        //newCaseNote.setParams({
        //  "studentId" : component.get("v.eventAttn").Student__c,
            //"studentName" : component.get("v.output"),
            //"eventId" : component.get("v.eventAttn").Event__c,
            //"eventName" : "Test",
            //"caseNoteDate" : new Date()});
        //newCaseNote.fire();
        
        //Send New Task event.//
    
        deleteItem: function(cmp,evt,helper){
        var eventAttn = cmp.get('v.eventAttn');
        var contactID = eventAttn.Student__c;
        var rosterList = cmp.get('v.rosterList'); 
        var contactOnRoster = false;
            var contactIndex = 0;  
        }, 
        

        rosterList.forEach( function(eventAttn, index){
            if(eventAttn.Student__c==contactID){
                contactOnRoster = true;
                contactIndex = index;
            },
        },
     
            rosterList.splice(contactIndex,1);
        console.log("rosterList post delete");
        console.dir(rosterList);
        

        //This is more elegant if I can avoid reseting Roster on every update.
        var rosterUpdateEvent = $A.get("e.c:RosterUpdateEvt");
        rosterUpdateEvent.setParams({
        "rosterList":rosterList,
        "eventAttn":eventAttn,
            "del":true,
            "newRoster":false
        });
        rosterUpdateEvent.fire();
})
```

## Error

[image]

## Edits after response

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `createRecord` function, right after `createRecordEvent.fire();`  you have `},` that close function itself, then `});` that close the controller, so everything that come after that line is outside the controller scope.
That's why it cannot find `deleteItem` on the controller.

You should remove that line, see below:

```js
createRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Task"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
},
  //  }); // Remove or comment this line
```

Comment: thank you so much for catching that. now that I have done that I get the error **Failed to save RosterLineItemCmpController.js: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.RosterLineItemCmp: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':', found 'FUNCTION' [47, 22]: Source**
 I have attached an image above <br> I have tried to add another }, before row 47 but that makes the button non-function  and then if I added at the end it makes the button do nothing. Any help woful be appreciated.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong and edited my posting to reflect changes